# Django image form isn't saving the image

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a form that involves uploading a profile picture. I have it working so that I can upload images in the `/admin/` interface and display them correctly, but I cannot get my `Modelform` to save the image.

Here is what I have:

#### models.py

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ElectionID = models.ForeignKey(Election, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ProfilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profilepics/", null=True, blank=True)
```

#### forms.py

```
class AddCandidateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = ['ElectionID', 'Bio', 'ProfilePicture']
```

#### cand_reg.html (Template)

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Register as a candidate</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Select an election:</h2><br>
        {{form.ElectionID}}<br>
        <h2>Enter your bio:</h2><br>
        {{form.Bio}}<br>
        <h2>Upload a profile picture:</h2><br>
        {{form.ProfilePicture}}<br>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I try the view function like so I get the error:
`MultiValueDictKeyError at /register/
"'ProfilePicture'"`

#### views.py

```
def add_candidate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCandidateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate = form.save(commit=False)
            candidate = request.FILES['ProfilePicture']
            candidate.UserID = request.user
            candidate.save()
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = AddCandidateForm()

    return render(request, 'cand_reg.html', {
        "form": form
    })
```

#### views.py

When I remove the offending line, the error goes away.

```
def add_candidate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCandidateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate = form.save(commit=False)
            # candidate = request.FILES['ProfilePicture']
            candidate.UserID = request.user
            candidate.save()
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = AddCandidateForm()

    return render(request, 'cand_reg.html', {
        "form": form
    })
```

However, this doesn't actually save the image, so when I try to render it in a separate template, I get an error then.

Can anyone help me understand why the image isn't uploading?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must set the `ProfilePicture` attribute of the model and **not** the instance itself (`candidate = request.FILES['ProfilePicture']`).

   Change to:

   ```
   candidate = form.save(commit=False)
   candidate.ProfilePicture = request.FILES['ProfilePicture']
   candidate.UserID = request.user
   candidate.save()
   ```
2. Change your HTML form to accept files as well. Change to: `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-form">`. When a form includes file inputs (`<input type="file" />`), then it must be encoded differently than it used when it includes only text. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). If you right-click and inspect the `{{form.ProfilePicture}}` you'll see that this is actually a file input.

Extra one:

1. Please, **do not** name your class attributes (`ProfilePicture`, `UserID` etc) in PascalCase. Use snake_case instead (`profile_picture`, `user_id` etc).

Comment: I made the change you advised, but still get the same error. Also, is there a particular reason for the extra changes you suggested?

Comment: After you change the `enctype` as suggested, you still get the same error?

Comment: Ah yes, that's it sorted. Thank you very much. What does that change that has made it work?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your question. Also, you **should** try to stay consistent with the snake_case lettering in `class` atts. Please, do yourself a favor and read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). It will not only help you but other Pythonistas also ;)